# Unable to access hard disk

Tags: mount, hard-drive

Whenever I try to mount my hard disk, it says:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/tj-depressing/KNOPPIX: Command-line
`mount -t "iso9660" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,
iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/tj-depressing/KNOPPIX"'
exited with non-zero exit status 32: 
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
missing codepage or helper program, or other error
In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
dmesg | tail or so.
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
If anyone could help then I would be very happy.

Comment: Try removing the `-t "iso9660"` option and let mount auto-detect the type

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem was caused due to an unsuccessful formatting of your storage.
Open terminal and type:

> sudo apt-get install gparted

Then in gparted do this:
[image]

After formatting the storage it will work correctly.